# Getting Unauthenticated warnings despite using permissions.AllowAny

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, drf-yasg

This is my APIView:

```
class VerifyEmail(APIView):
    serializer_class = EmailVerificationSerializer
    token_param_config = openapi.Parameter(
        'token',
        in_=openapi.IN_QUERY,
        description='Description',
        type=openapi.TYPE_STRING
    )
    @permission_classes([permissions.AllowAny])
    @swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[token_param_config])
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        try:
            payload = get_payload(request)
            user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
            if not user.is_verified:
                user.is_verified = True
                user.save()
            return Response({'email': 'Successfully activated'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Activation Expired'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except jwt.exceptions.DecodeError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid token'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

It is asking for authentication despite me mentioning `AllowAny`. I don't want this apiview to require authentication. The complete code is hosted [here](https://github.com/eadaradhiraj/DjangoJWT)

Comment: Are you passing the Authorization header with no or wrong token in the request header section? Sometimes if you do that then the API request will fail with unauthenticated error.

Comment: It should not require authentication

Comment: @MubashirAli Hi could you kindly take a look?

Comment: Why you are getting a token from the query param when that is not being used anywhere? If that is used for validation then please add that code, there might be some issues. Your current code example seems good to me. It should never ask for authentication since you are explicitly mentioning to allow all requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment the following lines:

```
     # user = get_user_obj(request)
            # if not user.is_verified:
            #     user.is_verified = True
            #     user.save()
```

in the `get` method.

`get_user_obj` is calling the `get_payload` method. Which is raising the `"Unauthenticated!"` error.

Here is the 200 response if I comment the lines.

[image]

Please change your logic for verifying emails. Here is a good guide.
https://www.rockandnull.com/django-email-verification/